# How can i use the register debug window in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, assembly, visual-studio-debugging, cpu-registers

I am currently learning assembly and i am using visual studio to do so. however when i went to evaluate the registers there was no option in the debug drop down. Would i need to install it or activate a setting?
Dont have enough reputation to embed a picture sorry.

Comment: Hi Linux, please check if harold's answer help you handle the issue? To open  `register debug window`, it should be under debugging process first and then you can find it. You can check these documents, [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-registers-window?view=vs-2019)and [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-basics-registers-window?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 6):

The registers window can be opened via **Debug > Windows > Registers**, when the debugger is active. In the normal editor mode, it does not show up as an option. The set of registers shown in the registers window can be changed via the right-click menu.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled **address-level** debugging in **Tools=> Options=> Debugging node**.

Don't forget to set a breakpoint, then run the the program in debugging mode.

If **you still can't see** the Register Option, consider the following: Go to **Tools => import and Export Settings => Reset all settings**.

Check "Yes, save my current settings," in case you may need to get your old settings back for some reason.

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-registers-window?view=vs-2019)

[Another Reference](https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/17949285.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do all the steps and check the things the people above me said but to seek the register option in the drop down window, set the break point and run the program and then go to the dropdown window. Now it should be there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33109742)